Ground state multiplicity of highly charged atomic ions
I tried to estimate what the electron configuration of charged atomic ions would have. I assumed they would be configured like their isoelectronic neutral element, i.e. Kr$^{8+}$ should be configured like Nickel as [Ar] 3d8 4s2, i.e. $^3$F . However, NIST says that Kr$^{8+}$ is [Ar] 3d10, i.e. $^1$S singlet instead. This deviation from the isoelectronics neutral configuration I found is true for Ni, Co, and Fe isoelectronics. The multiplicity is always reduced in these cases.
I thought about this in terms of the expectation values of Slater-Determinants and Configuration state function. Usually the multiplicity of the ground-state is as large as possible, which translates into more exchange energy and therefore lower energy. Now the positive charge of the cation will contract the wave function, but this should affect coulomb and exchange equally.
Does anyone have an idea in which direction to look, apart from running calculations?
